# Create an array of strings by selecting anchor's text for all the anchors element present in DOM

Tags: jquery

I need to create an array of anchor text like below:

```
$(currentNode).find('input:checkbox').next('a')
```

From above line of code I will get an object array of anchor elements, however I want an array of the text in the anchor elements.

My anchor tags are as below:

```
<a class="rightCaret" href="#subMenuSelect"> SelectMe </a>
```

and I need to create an array which contains it's text - i.e `SelectMe`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can use `.map()` and return the `text()` or `html()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` to build an array populated with the required properties. Try this:

```
var aTexts = $(currentNode).find('input:checkbox').next('a').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(aTexts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map()` function:

```
$(currentNode).find('input:checkbox').next('a').map(function(){
   return $(this).text()
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var array = $(currentNode).find('input:checkbox').next('a').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) you can do

```
var anchorTextA = [];
$(currentNode).find('input:checkbox').next('a').each(function(){
    anchorTextA.push($(this).text());
});
```